# AjaxMin stops after @media in css

Tags: css, microsoft-ajax-minifier

I added a step in my build task in VS2010 to minify my css and jss with AjaxMin.
However the minify messes up the css because when it reaches an @media tag it just stops. There are no errors in the build output.

basically at this point in the css:

```
.dropdown-submenu > ul {margin-left:20px;}

@media (min-width:768px) {
.blurb {margin:0 25px 25px 25px;}
}
```

in minifies to

```
.dropdown-submenu>ul{margin-left:20px}@media
```

and then is done. there is a lot more css after that @media tag, but looks like the minifier just stops.

This is my first time using the minifier, not sure if something is missing, or what could be happening?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What version of ajax minifier are you using? Seems this problem was fixed in version 5.7 https://ajaxmin.codeplex.com/workitem/20611

Comment: Pretty sure it is the latest version, I just downloaded and installed from that codeplex site - I can check Monday when I'm back at work. (just right click on the dll and check properties, right?).

Comment: Well I think that was it, I thought I had downloaded the version on the codeplex page, but maybe not? I reinstalled it and now it's seems to be working better. Thank you!

Comment: Cool! No problem